# Codeigniter formatted database select query rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.  mysql is the  database.
I have a query as shown below and it works perfectly.

```
$this->db->select(
                "orders.book_id,products.product_id,
                 products.price,orders.user_id,
                 products.parent_id,orders.booked_date
                "
        );

        $this->db->from("orders");
        $this->db->join('order_details', 'orders.book_id = order_details.book_id');
        $this->db->join('products', 'order_details.product_id = products.product_id');
```

I need to format the result and i know that can be done from PHP using some loop. But i have to do it using mysql for better performance.

I need to get a multi dimensional array with parent key as the key. 
Within that another set of arrays with product key as the key. 
The sample array i wish to get is written below. Is it possible to get 
the response in that format without looping through the  result?
Preferably using mysql itself?

```
Array
(
    //5 is parent id
    [5] => Array (
          //10 is product id
          [10] => Array(

              [0] => stdClass Object
              (
                    [book_id] => 345
                    [product_id] => 10
                    [price] => 12
                    [user_id] => 0
                    [parent_id] => 5
                    [booked_date] => 02-08-2016
              )


          )

          [7] => Array(

              [0] => stdClass Object
              (
                 [book_id] => 343
                 [product_id] => 7
                 [price] => 12
                 [user_id] => 34
                 [parent_id] => 5
                 [booked_date] => 02-08-2016
              )


          )

    )


    [1] => Array (

          [3] => Array(

              (
                 [book_id] => 341
                 [product_id] => 3
                 [price] => 11
                 [user_id] => 34
                 [parent_id] => 1
                 [booked_date] => 02-08-2016
               )


          )

          [11] => Array(

              [0] => stdClass Object
              (
                 [book_id] => 343
                 [product_id] => 11
                 [price] => 12
                 [user_id] => 34
                 [parent_id] => 1
                 [booked_date] => 02-08-2016
              )

              [1] => stdClass Object
              (
                [book_id] => 335
                [product_id] => 11
                [price] => 11
                [user_id] => 34
                [parent_id] => 1
                [booked_date] => 02-08-2016
              )


          )

    )

)
```

Comment: Not possible with MYSQL alone. You will have to use PHP

Comment: If possible with SQL queries only, it probably will perform much worse than doing it in PHP.